# How do you load a video file as a new material in a script in Unity Pro?

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to write a script for Unity Pro that loads a video texture upon the user using a key object on it. I'm various errors like "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" with the following code:

```
#pragma strict
static var isPlay : boolean = false;

function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
    if(other.CompareTag("key")) {
        print("Key!\n");
        isPlay = true;
    }
}

var movTexture : MovieTexture;

function Update() {
    if(isPlay) {
        movTexture = Resources.Load("VideoScraping/VidsList/20130324003252.mp4") as MovieTexture;
        renderer.material.mainTexture = movTexture;
        movTexture.Play();
    }
}
```

Is there another form of casting that I have to do to load the resource? Are movies loaded differently? Is there another element here that I'm missing?

Comment: Couple of simple things first.  Is your resource located in the Resources folder?  Where is the nullreference exception thrown, at Resources.Load or when you assign the texture to mainTexture?  Lastly, the way your Update is written once isPlay == true, Update will reload your movie texture every single frame.

Comment: It is located in the Assets folder. The nullreference seems to have been played at the movTexture.Play(); how would I rewrite it so that the Update only plays the movie once?

Answer (score 1):

So first possible fix, resource paths must be relative to /Assets/Resources.  From [Resources.Load():](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null.
>   The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder
>   of your project, extensions must be omitted.

Next is the question of playing the movie texture more than once.  For the purposes of your question I'm going to stick with your boolean flag example (changing isPlay -> triggerPlay):

```
if(triggerPlay) {
    movTexture = Resources.Load("VideoScraping/VidsList/20130324003252.mp4") as  MovieTexture;
    renderer.material.mainTexture = movTexture;
    movTexture.Play();
    triggerPlay = false; //Just swap the flag here.
}
```

This isn't ideal as OnTriggerEnter will set 'triggerPlay' to true regardless of whether the movie texture is playing.  In that respect you could move the movie playing code right in to OnTriggerEnter and get rid of the flag.  Or you could do something like:

```
var movTexture : MovieTexture;
function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider){
    if(other.CompareTag("key")&&!IsPlaying()){
        movTexture = Resources.Load("VideoScraping/VidsList/20130324003252.mp4") as  MovieTexture;
        renderer.material.mainTexture = movTexture;
        movTexture.Play();  
    }
}
function IsPlaying() :boolean {
    if(movTexture==null) return false;
    if(movTexture.isPlaying)return true;
    return false;
}
```

You could also use a [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) to play your movie, instead of using a flag, but that's a bit beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late to answer this question but I think you should not include file extension in
the Resoruces.Load() function.

```
 movTexture = Resources.Load("VideoScraping/VidsList/20130324003252") as  MovieTexture;
```